# Sorting ListView with Item, and after that - Sub item 1

Tags: c#

I want to sort my items and sub items like this:

```
one - a
one - b
one - c
three - apricot
three - banana
two - orange
two - pear
```

I've set Sorting to Ascending, but that only sorts the first column.

Comment: What are we sorting?  A list of strings?  If so, then there aren't 2 columns.  If not strings, then what is it?  More code please.

Comment: It is an ordinary ListView. I have string items in there, and string subitems to the items.

Like this: http://spunit.tk/x/scrn2_3.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `ListView.ListViewItemSorter` property to provide a custom `IComparer`. You have access to the `ListViewItem` and it's sub-items in the `Compare` method.

Here's an example of doing so (quickly thrown together). Note the comments in the code that explain what part is just setting up the sample `ListView`. There's very little code required to actually implement the sorting you want, and I've marked by comments where they are located. The only setup I did that isn't in the code is dropping a `ListView` on a new blank WinForm; the rest is done in the code, and there's a sample image below that shows the results.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.SuspendLayout();

      // This part is just setting up the ListView 
      // Turn off default sorting, and set to display columns
      this.listView1.Sorting = SortOrder.None;
      this.listView1.View = View.Details;

      // Add two columns (ColumnA and ColumnB)
      this.listView1.Columns.Add(new ColumnHeader());
      this.listView1.Columns[0].Width = 100;
      this.listView1.Columns[0].Text = "ColumnA";
      this.listView1.Columns.Add(new ColumnHeader());
      this.listView1.Columns[1].Width = 100;
      this.listView1.Columns[1].Text = "ColumnB";

      // Add the actual column information
      ListViewItem listViewItem1 = new ListViewItem(new String[] {"three", "banana"});
      ListViewItem listViewItem2 = new ListViewItem(new String[] {"one", "c"});
      ListViewItem listViewItem3 = new ListViewItem(new String[] {"one", "b"});
      ListViewItem listViewItem4 = new ListViewItem(new String[] {"three", "apricot"});
      this.listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[]{listViewItem1, 
                                                       listViewItem2, 
                                                       listViewItem3, 
                                                       listViewItem4});

      /*
         Now the actual sorting - this next line makes it sort using 
         the custom comparer we've defined. Assigning a new IComparer
         automatically sorts using it.
      */
      this.listView1.ListViewItemSorter = new ListViewItemComparer();

      this.ResumeLayout(false);
    }
  }

  // Implements the manual sorting of items by columns. 
  class ListViewItemComparer : IComparer  
  {
    public ListViewItemComparer()
    {

    }

    // This function actually does the comparison     
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
      /* 
         We need to access the same item multiple times, so
         save a local reference to reduce typecasting over and
         over again
      */
      ListViewItem FirstItem = (ListViewItem) x;
      ListViewItem SecondItem = (ListViewItem) y;

      /* 
         Compare the two columns of each item, combined to make 
         a single item for comparing.
      */
      return String.Compare(FirstItem.SubItems[0].Text + FirstItem.SubItems[1].Text,
                            SecondItem.SubItems[0].Text + SecondItem.SubItems[1].Text);
    }
  }
}
```

The results of running the above code (notice the items are not in the same order they were added):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I pasted all inside "public class ListViewSortForm : Form" in my Form1. I put the "class ListViewItemComparer : IComparer" at the very end of it all. However I get an error saying "Method must have a return type". I'm a real beginner at C# so excuse me if I'm a bit slow. This is my C# project: http://spunit.tk/x/PassPlace.rar

Comment: @spunit: I re-did the sample code and added the image for you. Read the new text and the code comments carefully.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I made it now =).